# What is a "note" (that might be published) in mathematics?

Tags: terminology, publishing

My background is not in mathematics but I am translating a novel from the French that has a few mathematicians as characters. A few times, the publication of a "note" is mentioned. This is the French word but I believe it would be the same in English.

There isn't much context for it, and so I was wondering if anyone could explain to me what a "note" is (assuming I have the correct terminology) in the field of mathematics. Is it something like a short comment on an article or theorem?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Also I should mention for context that this is taking place in France and Germany right before WWII.

Comment: Yes, a short mathematica comment, usually upon a larger, more-important publication.  A few mathematical journals publish such short notes.

Comment: This does happen in math from time to time but it's not nearly as common as it once was. I think this is just a side effect of the formalization of mathematics and the standards changing for mathematical journals. You'll often see something like a review article about a piece of work which might not have been presented in the best way or perhaps it might discuss how the ideas are applicable to another problem/area of mathematics. This kind of publication is still somewhat common in the physical sciences.